# PagingAndSortingRepository how to sort case insensitive?

Tags: java, sorting, spring-boot, repository, thymeleaf

My Problem is that my code sorts the result case-sensitive.

Below you see my code:

```
    @GetMapping("/user/api_key_list")
    public ModelAndView apiKeyList(Model model,
                                   @RequestParam("pageSize") Optional<Integer> pageSize,
                                   @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page,
                                   @RequestParam("sortBy") Optional<String> sortBy
    ) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user/apikeylist");
        int evalPageSize = pageSize.orElse(INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE);
        int evalPage = (page.orElse(0) < 1) ? INITIAL_PAGE : page.get() - 1;
        String sortOrder = sortBy.orElse(INITIAL_SORT);
        String[] sort = sortOrder.split(",");
        String evalSort = sort[0];
        String sortDirection = sort[1];
        Sort.Direction evalDirection = replaceOrderStringThroughDirection(sortDirection);
        Page<ApiKey> apiKeyList = apiKeyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(evalPage, evalPageSize, evalDirection, evalSort));
        PagerModel pager = new PagerModel(apiKeyList.getTotalPages(), apiKeyList.getNumber(), BUTTONS_TO_SHOW);
        modelAndView.addObject("apiKeyList", apiKeyList);
        modelAndView.addObject("selectedPageSize", evalPageSize);
        modelAndView.addObject("pageSizes", PAGE_SIZES);
        modelAndView.addObject("pager", pager);
        modelAndView.addObject("selectedSort", String.format("%s,%s", evalSort, sortDirection));
        modelAndView.addObject("sorts", SORTS);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

My question is: How can I sort it case-insensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you are using  spring-data-jpa you can do like this

```
Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "columnName").ignoreCase();
```

and pass this Order in query.

In your case

```
Page<ApiKey> apiKeyList = apiKeyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(evalPage, evalPageSize, new Sort(order)));
```

**Edit 1:**

For newer version of Spring above method is deprecated.

just adding code added by Dullimeister to complete answer

```
Sort sortOrderIgnoreCase = Sort.by(new Sort.Order(evalDirection,evalSort).ignoreCase());
```

Comment: The problem is, if I use `new Sort(order)` it is deprecated.

Comment: you can look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html  for other sort functions which are not deprecated. just pass parameter accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Sort.Order`:

```
Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(evalDirection , evalSort).ignoreCase();

Page<ApiKey> apiKeyList = apiKeyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(evalPage, evalPageSize, new Sort(order)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it

```
    //    Query query = new Query();
        Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "columnName");
   //     query.with( Sort.by(order));

        Page<ApiKey> apiKeyList = apiKeyRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(evalPage, evalPageSize, new Sort(order)));
```

Adding comments so it can help other people too.