# Pagable Sort.Order ignore case

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, pageable

(I'm using Micronaut)
I have a list of students and I want to sort it by name. I am using Pageable and sort as query parameters

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/students?page=0&size=10&sort=name,asc&status=graduated
```

and I get this result:

- Samantha
- Tim
- antonio
- david
- sofia

Instead of:

- antonio
- david
- Samantha
- sofia
- Tim

I have tried the options using Sort.Order, based on

[PagingAndSortingRepository how to sort case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816071/pagingandsortingrepository-how-to-sort-case-insensitive)

[Spring Data JPA: case insensitive orderBy](http://Spring%20Data%20JPA:%20case%20insensitive%20orderBy)

I removed the sorting from my url and tried if Sort.Order works

```
Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order("name",Sort.Order.Direction.ASC, true);

http://localhost:8080/admin/students?page=0&size=10&status=graduated
```

but it didn't, it doesn't do any sorting neither

Steps:

1. Repository, added Sort.Order

   ```
    @Repository
    public interface StudentRepository extends PageableRepository<Student, Long> {

       Page<Student> findByGraduatedIsNull(Student.Status status, @Nullable Pageable p, Sort.Order sort);

    }
   ```
2. Service

   ```
    public Page<Student> getStudents(Student.Status status, Pageable pageable){

        Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order("name",Sort.Order.Direction.ASC, true);
        Page<Student> studentPage =
                        studentRepository.findByGraduatedIsNull(status, pageable, order);
        return studentPage.map(s -> studentTransform.toDto(s));

    }
   ```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `Pageable` interface supports sorting, so not sure why you would pass both a `Pageable` and `Sort.Order` parameter (I don't know if that is even supported). If no sort was defined on the URL, the `getSort()` on `Pageable` should return `UNSORTED`. So that may be taking precedent over the `Sort.Order`.

Why don't you check if a sort was passed in on the request, and if not default it to the sort you want or simply override it if you don't want to allow a sort to be passed in.

```csharp
if (pageable.getSort == Sort.unsorted()) {
    List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    orders.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name").ignoreCase()); 
    pageable = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), Sort.by(orders));
}
        
Page<Student> studentPage = studentRepository.findByGraduatedIsNull(status, pageable)
```